# Trying to access a v2 endpoint hosted webapi but no luck, true if only graph api works on v2 now?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Had a webapi running on v2 endpoint, the intent was to get access through a single call to both graph and the custom webapi, was using the v2 auth code grant flow, the url using as below,

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=14e9111f3e1-d220-415d-9bf4-d089f0b5feff&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fartifactory%2Fwebapp%2Fsaml%2FloginResponse&response_mode=query&scope=api%3A%2F%2F14e9f3e1-d220-415d-9bf4-d089f0b5feff%2Faccess_as_user%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fuser.read%20openid%20offline_access&state=12345
```

with the scope as

```
api://14e9f3e1-d220-415d-9bf4-d089f0b5feff/access_as_user https://graph.windows.net/user.read openid offline_access
```

However, keep failing with a invalid scope error. If I take out the custom webapi from the resource, everything went through wonderfully.

Reading further, there is a limitation for webpi that

> Web API can receive tokens only from an application that has the same Application ID. You cannot access a Web API from a client that has a different Application ID.

***So I am confused, how to archieve the goal to use v2 endpoint to authenticate and get access to both graph and webapi????***

--edit
the error message is 'AADSTS65005: The application 'blah' asked for scope 'user.read' that doesn't exist on the resource. Contact the app vendor.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today the v2 endpoint cannot issue an access token for a custom API. The feature is in active development, but there's no ETA to share.
Also note: even when the feature will be available, you will not be able to reuse the same access token across multiple resources; you'll be able to consent for multiple resources at once, so that your user is only promoted once, but you will need to request access tokens for each resources separately.

Comment: this is very sad.. thanks for the answer, it is very clear!! how come it works for graph? and i can request multiple scope within the same call, e.g. mail.read, mail.send etc..

Comment: We hope to have the feature out very soon, apologies for the inconvenience. You can definitely ask multiple scopes for the graph: the resulting token will reflect that.

Comment: Sorry forget to ask this, by very soon when should we expect it ther,

Comment: In days, weeks or a month:) we have a vendor they truly expect this feature :) any ticket tracking this feature?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is no ETA to share at this time

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2017/06/22/web-api-and-custom-scope-with-azure-ad-v2-endpoint/ why is this work then or this guy is writing I the future?

Comment: That's a very limited case, you can't even get refresh tokens with it at this time. The feature is being worked on do there are sub scenarios that can work but there are multiple caveats (absence of refresh tokens, not working with libraries, no combined consent etc etc etc) hence trying something to that effect is at your own risk

Comment: thanks for clarify, btw, that article doesn't work for me at all.. i